# ¿Qué significa llevar un proyecto a ''producción''?

Tags: ingenieria-del-software

He visto que dicen mucho que ''En producción esto..'', ''para llevar tu proyecto a producción..'' y me confunde esa definición. Espero me puedan resolver la duda de que significa llevar un proyecto a producción. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Es cuando se publica en un servidor y ya es usable para el cliente final.

Answer (score 14):

### ML;NL (Muy Largo, no leí o TL;DR)

Un proyecto que ya está en producción es un proyecto, en un estado usable, probado (idealmente), que se encuentra en un servidor (ya sea público o local) ya accesible al cliente o usuario final.

Por lo general un proyecto puede correr en distintos entornos. Los más comunes de éstos son:

## Desarrollo (development)

Una aplicación corre en este modo cuando aún se está desarrollando. Por ejemplo, para el caso de una aplicación web, si sigues manipulando el código y haciendo pruebas locales en tu máquina, estás en la fase de desarrollo.

## Prueba (test)

Si estás haciendo desarrollo con pruebas unitarias (Test Driven Development), programarás pruebas que garanticen que tu aplicación funciona y cumple con una serie de requerimientos. Cuando ejecutas estas pruebas, muchas veces quieres tener ciertos datos fijos y ejecutar tu aplicación con una configuración determinada. Para ello existe este entorno.

## Pruebas de producción (staging)

Ya que tu aplicación está casi lista, querrás hacer pruebas casi como se verá. Probablemente la cargues a un servidor de prueba, cuya configuración será prácticamente idéntica a la del servidor en la que correrá finalmente tu aplicación. Sin emabrgo, es posible que deshabilites cierta funcionalidad, como envíos de correo o conexión a servicios externos para evitar costos innecesarios en esta etapa. Por lo general en este modo se corren las pruebas de aceptación.

## Producción (production)

Es el entorno en el que corre la aplicación que ya utilizará el usuario final. Para este punto toda la funcionalidad de la aplicación debe estar disponible y cualquier conexión con un servicio externo debe estar habilitada.

Puedes consultar [esta referencia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development,_testing,_acceptance_and_production) para entender mejor las fases de desarrollo de Software basados en pruebas.

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿por qué inicias con "*ML;NL*"? Entiendo el significado, pero ¿por qué utilizarlo en este caso? No digo que esté mal, simplemente no me hace sentido, talvez con tu explicación me quede más claro

Comment: Es una traducción, no sé si mala o no... A muchos desarrolladores les da flojera leer y cantidad de artículos en inglés inician con una sección de TL;DR (Too Long; Didn't Read) en la que se pone un resumen de la respuesta, o lo que más interesa saber. Como nunca había contestado en un foro de tecnología en español, no supe si era usado o no.

Comment: Ah muy bien, si fue una traducción también sería bueno que pusieras la fuente, no tiene nada de malo, con eso vamos alimentando la base de conocimientos en [es.so] ;)

Comment: Yo he entendido que lo que es una traduccion es lo de ML;NL (de TL;DR). No el texto en sí. Aún asi el TL;DR se pone al final del texto siempre no?

Comment: Sí, claro. Como dice @DanielFaro, solo el ML;NL es una traducción del TL;DR. El resto de la respuesta es escrita por mi. Con respecto a lo comentas, Daniel, he visto TL;DR tanto al principio como al final de artículos / respuestas.

Comment: A mi me parece más útil el ML;NL al principio. Es el mejor sitio si quiero saltarme todo lo demas. Muy completa respuesta pero yo cambiaría una cosa. El que un servidor esté o no accesible por el público no tiene nada que ver con que esté en producción. Multitud de servidores están en producción y se encuentran en redes locales no accesibles por el público.

Comment: De acuerdo. Ya la edité.

Answer (score 6):

Es un termino de la industria del software que se utiliza principalmente cuando un sistema informático ha sido desplegado para que el usuario final pueda interaccionar con el mismo y/o haciendo las funciones para las cuales fue concebido en la etapa de requerimientos.

Answer (score 5):

Un sistema en producción es un sistema desplegado con acceso del usuario o cliente final con la meta de ser parte en un proceso productivo, a decir participando en un proceso de creación de valor agregado.

Una beta cerrada (con usuarios de prueba preseleccionado) por ejemplo no es un proyecto en producción, una beta abierta, aun en etapa de prueba, lo es.

El termino también se usa mucho para recursos. Un servidor en producción por ejemplo es un servidor que es publicamente accesible, en contrario a un servidor de pruebas que sirve para comprobar artefactos antes del lanzamiento o un servidor de facilitación (staging server, quizás alguien tiene una mejor traducción).

Comment: Es discutible que una beta abierta sea un producto en producción. Con una beta abierta puedes hacer cosas como borrarlo todo y hacer que los usuarios empiecen de cero o publicar cambios no compatibles hacia atras; los cuales no harías en un sistema en producción. Pero también es verdad que hay betas y betas y hay algunas que casi no se diferencian de un sistema en producción. Respecto de un servidor el que esté en producción o no tiene poco que ver con que esté en producción. Por ejemplo los servidores de control de misión de la ESA no son accesibles al público y sí están en producción.

Comment: Si lo es, pero no lo digas a nadie, porque todo lo discutible se cierra aquí en cero tiempo ;) Decir categoricamente que lo es es igual de equivocado que decir categoricamente que no lo es, en mi experiencia y en la mayoría de los casos sirve como tesis valido para operar.

Answer (score 1):

"En producción" tiene sentido al usarlo en contraposición a "En desarrollo".

A nivel de seguridad, puede que durante el desarrollo relajes algunas condiciones para facilitarte la vida, mientras que en producción corres con todas las restricciones de seguridad en su lugar.

A nivel de máquina, el desarrollo lo puedes hacer en tu máquina local o en una máquina destinada a desarrollar, donde coexisten varios proyectos en verde. En producción, el producto debiera correr en su propia máquina con sólo lo mínimo para que éste corra. Esa instalación debiera ser reproducible y desplegable sin participación de un operador.

A nivel de código, en desarrollo puede que te permitas mostrar mensajes de debug en la consola o por pantalla, lo mismo con los mensajes de error. En producción en cambio el usuario no tiene por qué ver los errores explícitamente, más bien debiera mostrársele un aviso de que "algo salió mal" y por debajo almacenar el error real en un log.

A nivel de monitoreo, no tiene mucho sentido monitorear una instalación de desarrollo. Una instalación de producción, en cambio, debiera tener monitoreo de uptime, tiempo de respuesta, peticiones encoladas, visitas únicas, etc etc.

A nivel de empaquetamiento y cachés, en desarrollo trabajas con la fuente del código y lo compilas en tiempo de ejecución o cada vez que lo vas a correr, porque quieres ir viendo los cambios conforme los vas haciendo. En producción querrías tener el código empaquetado y así ahorrarte el paso de compilación al ejecutar. Aplicado a lenguajes que se interpretan en cada request como PHP, la diferencia está en que durante el desarrollo querrías correr la aplicación sin caché de variables ni opcode, de nuevo para ver los cambios conforme los vas haciendo.

Comment: No concuerdo que dices que en la etapa de desarrollo el monitoreo no tiene mucho sentido. Tiene **otro** sentido, y si es solo para juntar datos que pueden servir como valores de referencia en la producción después para identificar anormalidades.

Comment: Bueno, nadie desaconseja el monitoreo, pero su utilidad es cuestión de opinión. Lo importante es no mezclar los kpi de cada aplicación en un mismo silo de mediciones.

Answer (score 0):

Describe la puesta en marcha de un sistema o programa que previamente estuvo desarrollando.

Si el cliente o "product owner" acepta el producto, se despliega a un entorno de producción, poniéndolo a disposición de todos los usuarios del sistema.

Un entorno de producción es el lugar donde se ejecutan los sistemas o programas que ejecutan una organización en tiempo real, e incluye el personal, los procesos, los datos, el hardware y el software necesarios para realizar las operaciones diarias.

Answer (score -1):

En producción es cuando la aplicación ya está lista para ser usada por el usuario final, o sea subida al servidor final donde se desplegará la app

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).  Tu respuesta no parece aportar nada nuevo a lo que ya han contestado otros, más bien duplicas la misma información. Te recomiendo leerte [Cómo escribo una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). También puede interesarte realizar el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)